# Extension method to remove not primitive property of an object

Tags: c#, json, .net

I'd like an extension method to create an object based on another but keep only the primitive properties. This object will be dumped into a log file in JSON format for logging.

Based on the classes shown below, in this sample, the created object should keep only these properties :

```
public string  FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public int Age { get; set; }
```

I am using .NET Framework 4.7

How can I do this?

```
// To use like this
var order = new Order();
var forLog = order.RemovePrimitives();

// Sample of classes
public class Order
{
    public string  FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Item{}

public class Address{}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static string RemovePrimitives(this object obj)
    {
        // I need to create an anonymous, named 'TheNewObjectHere' object but only with primitives
        // I will dump the object to push to a log file. I need only primitives
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TheNewObjectHere, Formatting.Indented);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: C# is not JavaScript/TypeScript: C# uses a nominal (not structural) static type system so you can't create new objects (of new types) at runtime (...at least, not without reflection) and iterate over members like that.

Comment: Rather than "duplicating" an object, it sounds like you just want to _dump_ public members of objects (i.e. serialize for logging/diag purpoises) instead - is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Dai Sure. Reflection is ok to me. Indeed "Duplicate" it's not the right word.

Comment: Anonymous objects are still created at compile time so this isn't possible like you ask. You'd probably be better off with a Dictionary of values instead, assuming you don't want nested properties.

Comment: "I use C# 7.4" - there's no such version. After C# 7.3, the next version is 8.

Comment: @DavidG Indeed.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oooops it's corrected it's .NET framework 4.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string RemovePrimitives(this object obj)
    {
        var jsonObj = JObject.FromObject(obj);

        var propToRemove = jsonObj.Properties().Where(i => !i.Value.GetType().ToString()
                                                            .Contains("JValue")).ToList();

        foreach (var prop in propToRemove) prop.Remove();

        return jsonObj.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Works. But I forgot something. The object comes from EF. That's means some of  these 'not primitive' are proxies : Address = {System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Order_BF2B4E9F43AC0ABB816A3E515DA7083B49FF4581E6BB8FBCDD83FF466EB91DAA}  Is it possible to remove them too ?

Comment: @Kris-I Did you try the code? it should remove everything

Comment: Yes with your code I get this error "'Self referencing loop detected with type" on line JObject.FromObject(obj); Exceptions only when the nested object is a proxy.

Comment: @Kris-I Unfortunately I can not reproduce it, but can you use [JsonIgnore] attribute to this property? Oherwise you have to configure self referending options of Newtosonft.Json. But it is out of the scope this question

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to get primitive properties and then use `JObject` to build a JSON object dynamically.

```
public static readonly Type[] AdditionalPrimities = new[] { typeof(decimal), typeof(string) };

    public static string RemovePrimitives<T>(this T obj)
    {
        var jObj = new JObject();
        var props = GetPrimitiveProperties(obj);

        foreach (var item in props)
        {
            var value = item.GetValue(obj);
            if (value != null)
            {
                jObj.Add(item.Name, new JValue(value));
            }
        }

        return jObj.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    }

    public static PropertyInfo[] GetPrimitiveProperties<T>()
    {
        var properties = typeof(T)
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
           .Where(r => r.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || (r.PropertyType.IsGenericType && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(r.PropertyType) != null) || AdditionalPrimities.Contains(r.PropertyType))
            .Select(r => r)
            .ToArray();


        return properties;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var order = new Order { FirstName = "abc", LastName = "cde", Address = new Address(), Age2 = 3, Age = 1 };
        var final = order.RemovePrimitives();

        Console.WriteLine(final);
    }
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HWnkCG)